# Non-invocable member "....Models.MainModels.Menu" cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1, html-agility-pack, win-universal-app

Here is first time I do this type.
Inside Models:
Menu.cs

```
public class Menu
{
    private string _iconThumb;
    public string IconThumb
    {
        get
        {
            return _iconThumb;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value!=_iconThumb)
            {
                _iconThumb = value;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

and MainModels.cs

```
 public class MainModels
{

    public ObservableCollection<Menu> Menu { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loading all of information menus to Listbox.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// 
    public ObservableCollection<Menu> MenuLoad()
    {
        Menu = new ObservableCollection<Menu>();
        {
            new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/align_justify-50.png" };
            new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/music_video-50.png" };
            new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/christmas_star-50.png" };
            new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/user-50.png" };
        }
        return Menu;
    }
```

MainPages.cs

```
Models.MainModels Main = new Models.MainModels();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        loaddata();
        Menu();

    }
    //Loading menu in main
    private void Menu()
    {
        lstMenu.ItemsSource = Main.Menu;
    }
```

Error:

> Non-invocable member "....Models.MainModels.Menu" canot be used like a method.

I don't know to solve this problem because of I'm in the first times do this.

Answer (score 0):

The `Menu` is a property of the `MainModels` class, not a method. So, please remove the parentheses for the method call: `lstMenu.ItemsSource = Main.Menu;`.

Please consider using the following implementation of `MainModels` class:

```
public class MainModels
{
    public MainModels()
    {
        Menu = new ObservableCollection<Menu>(GetMenuItems());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Menu> Menu { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Factory method to return all "known" menu items.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    private static IEnumerable<Menu> GetMenuItems()
    {
        var items = new[]
            {
                new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/align_justify-50.png" };
                new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/music_video-50.png" };
                new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/christmas_star-50.png" };
                new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/user-50.png" };
            }
            .ToList()
            .AsReadOnly();
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: No error but Not loading on listbox. I had make debug it but when went to at " lstMenu.ItemsSource = Main.Menu;" then end up debuger.

`public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            loaddata();
            Menu();
        }`

Comment: Sorry.I'm nood. I didn't see `ToList()` and `AsReaOnly()`

Comment: Basically, I success.
`public ObservableCollection<Menu> MenuLoad()
        {
            menu = new ObservableCollection<Menu>();
            
                menu.Add(new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/align_justify-50.png", Name="List" });
                menu.Add (new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/music_video-50.png", Name="Video" });
                menu.Add(new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/christmas_star-50.png", Name="Favourite" });
                menu.Add(new Menu() { IconThumb = "/Photos/user-50.png", Name="Profile" });
                return menu;
        }`

Comment: I liked your code. So you will help to me to solve it.